# Android Synchronizing application

Tags: android

I have an xml file in a server. I want to sync that file in my android application. Is there any way to do that . please help.

Comment: please explain what you mean by "sync" in detail.

Comment: @Chris sync means synchronization, when ever I change the file in server it should be reflected in the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html for an example of how to create an Android SyncAdapter.